# Set style value depending on a boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I use a component by passing a boolean props called small

```
<CustomItem title={item.title} small={true} />
```

In CustomItem I want to do something like

```
 const small = this.props.small;

<Text style={[styles.title]}> {title} </Text>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    title:{
    fontSize: small ? 10 : 20, // error here 
    fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
```

But I get an error "Can't find variable small"

Comment: Is CustomerItem a presentational component (a function)  or a container component (a class)?  If its a presentational component then using the `this` keyword would result in the small variable being unfound.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are addressing this the wrong way. The correct way of doing this would be to create a separate style and then apply it condicionally this way :

```
const small = this.props.small;
<Text 
    style={[styles.title, small && styles.small]}
> 
    {title}
</Text>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    small: {
        fontSize: 10
    }
})
```

So now you apply a small where you can do further configuration and is easier to maintain in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
const small = this.props.small;
//add conditional statement here 
<Text style={[styles.title, { fontSize: small ? 10 : 20 }]}> {title} </Text>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    title:{
    // removed fontSize here
    fontWeight: 'bold'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are instantiating `small` in your component whereas you are creating `Stylesheet` outside of your component. `small`'s scope is limited to the component and hence you can't access `small` from outside the component. You need to do this:

```
    const small = this.props.small;
    <Text style={[styles.title, {fontSize: small ? 10 : 20} ]}> {title} </Text>
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        title:{ 
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
    })
```